# panel not working in all pages using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

Hi friends I am new in jQuery mobile and trying to learns things by creating a website using jquery mobile. The problem is I used `data-role="panel"` to show navigation on my page its working fine but when i jump to another page which is in same HTML file its stop working I dont know what is the matter for crack this issue need your help. **[You can check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UbT9u/)**. On home page panel work fine but when i click on about us page its jump there but panel stops working

Please help me guys .. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to access the same panel from any pages, you have to place panel div outside any `data-role="page"`, and then you have to initialize it manually. This is called an *external panel*.

```
<body>
  <div data-role="panel" id="foo" data-theme="a">
    <!-- contents -->
  </div>

  <!-- pages here -->
</body>
```

Note that an *external panel* doesn't inherit theme automatically, thus, you need to add `data-theme` attribute to it.

The `.enhanceWithin()` function is to enhance all widgets inside the panel. They aren't auto-initialized, so they need to be initialized.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=panel]").enhanceWithin().panel();
});
```

Place that code in head after JQM library.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UbT9u/1/)**

Comment: thanks for consideration @Omar.. If you dont mind will u please share fiddle here

Comment: You're welcome @Kamal, I'm glad I've been of help :)