# Swipe not working in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am learning jquery mobile and want to do the swipe menu on my website.

In my header, I have loaded the scripts:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-css-css'  href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.105/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.105/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.105/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mag/js/responsive-menu.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js?ver=1.4.0'></script>
```

I load these scripts as below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'magazine_enqueue_scripts' );

function magazine_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400|Raleway:400,500,900', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-css','http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magazine-entry-date', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/entry-date.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'magazine-responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mobile','http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js',array('jquery'),'1.4.0');
}
```

In the responsive-menu.js, I have

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
$(".site-container").on('swiperight', function (e) {$('#menu-panel').panel('open');}
$(".site-container").on('swipeleft', function (e) {$('#menu-panel').panel('close');}
);  
});
```

The html structure is:

```
<body>
<div id="menu-panel" data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal"></div>
<div class="site-container"></div>
</body>
```

Also, because I was using a wordpress template, I had to add by code the div for menu-panel. I did it as below:

```
add_action('genesis_before','magazine_menu_panel');
function magazine_menu_panel()
{
   echo '<div id="menu-panel" data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal"></div>';
}
```

But,  I don't know why it is not working.

Here is a link to the code I am using : http://fiddle.jshell.net/2B4Ht/11/

By the way, this is the first time I am posting a question here, so if there is any more information that I should provide, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Ok i added the code too. :)

Comment: If you open your development console, you should see an error in jQuery Mobile when your fiddle loads. That's probably because jQuery Core is included after jQuery Mobile, you want to include it before, like you do in the code you posted.

Comment: You're using old style sheet. Use the one associated with JQM 1.4

Comment: I updated and cleaned your [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2B4Ht/14/) which is working, at least using my mouse on my laptop, I don't know if it works on smartphones/tablets, but since jQuery Mobile uses touchs event when it can, this should work.

Comment: This answer explains how to use an external panel in JQM 1.4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857208/panel-not-working-in-all-pages-using-jquery-mobile/21857463#21857463

Comment: I can recommend you one swipe menu that I'm using in [one of my projects](http://jmarqz.w.pw/Matinal/) and works perfectly. I'm using JMQ 1.3 and JQ 1.11, but it works for JQM 1.4 too, the swipe menu calls: [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). It's responsive and actually works in a native app too (I've already prove it).

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I will check each one today.